# Difficulty making 3 JOINS when 2 and 2 joins work just fine

Tags: sql

I have a problem. When I do a simple join on 2 tables everything works great. No repetitions. Everything sums up.

[enter image description here][1]

```
      SELECT S.ITEM, SUM(QTY)
      FROM smm S
      JOIN pmmm P
      ON S.ITEM=P.ITEM AND P.DEST=S.LOC 
      GROUP BY s.ITEM, p.qty
```

What can be wrong with 3 joins if 2 and 2 joins work just fine but when I combine all of them I start getting repetitions.

pmmm table doesn't have unique Item and Dest. If someone may know how I can pre-aggregate it and add it to the code

Comment: THis is how joins work. If one record in one atble matches three records in another table, the result is three records. Either you need to find the correct join colunms, or you need t pre-aggregate the join table to be unique in the join columns. It looks like the table `PLANARRIV` is the issue. So `Item` and `Dest` must not be unique in this table.

Comment: It looks like a problem of cartesian product, due to joins made on columns that are not the full PK. Could you please describe your tables, including IDs / PKs for each of them?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  yes, PLANARRIV has Item and Dest that are not unique. Is there a way to pre-aggregate one table and later add it to the code that I have written before?

Comment: It looks like you have a logic issue.  It's unlikely you want `qty` in the `GROUP BY` terms of either query.  Are you sure you want that?  Is so, can you explain the logic behind that?  I'm asking about the original queries, before you tried to `JOIN` more tables.

Comment: Please tag the question with the database you're using, and include the logical requirement.  For instance, if you expect to have a result with one row per (`item`, `sum1`, `sum2`) tuple, where the result is contains a distinct list of items, mention that.  If an `item` could be in the result more than once, explain that logic too.

Comment: Taking @JonArmstrong comment further, when you have two records with different `qty` how do you want to boil that down to one record? Do you want to sum them?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.  Note: I've removed a few terms from your `GROUP BY` clause, since that looked like a mistake.  Feel free to adjust as needed.

My assumption is that you just wanted each `SUM` per `item` to be joined together.

If you wanted sums per (item, location) pair, that's different.  But we wouldn't place `qty` in the `GROUP BY` terms to do that.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
       SELECT S.ITEM, SUM(QTY) AS sum1
         FROM SCPOMGR.SKU       S
         JOIN SCPOMGR.PLANARRIV P
           ON S.ITEM=P.ITEM
          AND P.DEST=S.LOC 
        GROUP BY s.ITEM
     )
   , cte2 AS (
       SELECT S.ITEM
            , SUM(QTY) AS sum2
         FROM SCPOMGR.SKU     S
         JOIN SCPOMGR.RECSHIP R
           ON S.ITEM=R.ITEM
          AND S.LOC = R.SOURCE
        GROUP BY S.ITEM
     )
SELECT cte1.item, cte1.sum1, cte2.sum2
  FROM cte1
  JOIN cte2
    ON cte1.item = cte2.item
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Correlated subqueries can work well here:

```
  SELECT S.ITEM,
         (SELECT SUM(P.QTY)
          FROM SCPOMGR.PLANARRIV P
          WHERE S.ITEM = P.ITEM AND P.DEST = S.LOC
         ),
         (SELECT SUM(P.QTY)
          FROM SCPOMGR.RECSHIP R
          WHERE S.ITEM = R.ITEM AND S.LOC = kR.SOURCE
         ),
  FROM SCPOMGR.SKU S;
```